# Couldn't load PyQGIS, QGIS 2.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 Precise

Tags: qgis, python, ubuntu, sip

After upgrading to QGIS 2.0.1 I still get the error:

`Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/**init**.py", line 63, in 
    from qgis import core
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v10.0 to v10.1 but the qgis.core module requires API v8.1

I have installed the latest python-qgis package (2.0.1-2+precise1). Am I missing something the right (older) SIP package?

Comment: When I open QGIS 2.0.1 in Linux Mint 15, I get an "[ERROR] Can not make qgis.db private copy" first and then a  "Couldn't load plugin processing due an error when calling its classFactory() method". However, the program opens up.